# pytest live logs with different packages

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.7

During my `pytest` runs I would like to see the `DEBUG` output for some loggers while suppressing the `DEBUG` output for other libraries.

According to https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html
I have the following config:

```
# setup.cfg
[tool:pytest]
addopts = log_cli=true --log-cli-level=debug
```

The test file looks like following:

```
# test_functions.py
...
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN)
# alternatively I also tried
# logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARN)
logging.getLogger("mylogger").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def test_myfunction():
    ...
```

The problem now is. I still get all `DEBUG` output from all modules (especially 3rd party libraries).

**How do I suppress all other logging.DEBUG output?**

Comment: `--log-cli-level=debug` is assigned to root logger and can't be overridden; your question is effectively "How do I suppress all child loggers except for selected ones". Best one would be configuring the child loggers directly, e.g. `logging.getLogger('somelib').propagate = False`. You can also check for registered loggers in a fixture, e.g. `for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict: logging.getLogger(name).propagate = False`, but it depends on when a particular library registers its loggers.

Comment: Thanks, I would accept this as an answer.
Looks quite tedious to me. I am just wondering, if it something is wrong with my workflow that is uncommon.(when writing tests against a web api I would like to read my logs to see what is actually happening also to adjust my assertions)

Comment: IMO the reason is the simplicity of live logs feature so that you can't really tune any logging settings besides the global level or format. I would also enjoy a bit more sophisticated configuration possibility via e.g. `dictConfig`, but we have what we have :-)